# does Pyvot require Visual Studio?

Tags: python, excel

Possibly a dumb question, but after a lot of searching, I haven't yet found an unambiguous answer. The [site](http://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Pyvot) states

> Pyvot requires CPython 2.6 or 2.7 with the Python for Windows
>   extensions (pywin32) installed, and Office 2010.

Although there's no mention of Visual Studio, it could well be assumed since the page is titled "Python Tools for Visual Studio." If anyone *has* run it successfully without VS, I'd love to know (I don't currently have Office 2010, or I'd try it myself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get a hold of Office 2010 and can confirm that Pyvot doesn't require Visual Studio or even Python Tools for Visual Studio.

[EDIT: Although I haven't tested extensively, it seems to work just fine with Office 2003!]